# How to force google to allow user to choose accounts during oauth?

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, oauth

Im currently trying to integrate some support for google apps (e.g. use your google calendar while on this website, etc) - and Im currently trying to do it with their api via oauth2

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

Unfortunately, a weird quirk is that, google automatically tries to authenticate oauth2 with the user's currently signed in account. Is it possible to force google to allow users to pick an account by specifying some sort of query parameter in `step1_get_authorize_url()`?

Like this
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following parameter is supported in OAuth2 authorization URLs:

prompt

Currently it can have values 'none', 'select_account', and 'consent'.

select_account: Will cause the account selector to display, even if there's a single logged-in user, just as you asked.

prompt=select_account

Comment: Thanks, can I ask where you found this info? Ive been combing the docs for hours

Comment: @Alan go to https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference and look under Google auth signin options.